# Confusões com JSON.stringify, JSON.parse e OBJECT.push()

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Bom estou me embolando com estes comandos, na real o que estou querendo fazer é o seguinte. Utilizando `localStorage` manter um banco de dados.

```
NOME TABELA | DADOS TABELA
tbl_TESTE   | {teste 01, teste02, teste03, ...}
tbl_TESTE02 | {arroz, feijão, batata, ...}

**Sendo que todos os dados da tabela é um array de OBJETOS.
```

Quando inicio a aplicação estou setando os bancos como nulos faço assim:

```
localStorage.setItem("tbl_TABELA01", []);
localStorage.setItem("tbl_TABELA02", []);
localStorage.setItem("tbl_TAVELA03", []);
```

Isto é feito apenas uma vez para não zerar os dados ja inseridos.

Após ao inserir faço da seguinte maneira:

```
var nome = $("#lblNome").val(),
    telefone = $("#lblTelefone").val();

var dados = [];

   dados.lbNome = nome;
   dados.lbTelefone = telefone;

   console.log(dados);

//var result = JSON.stringify(dados);

// console.log(result);

var tbl_CELULAS = localStorage.getItem("tbl_CELULAS");

   console.log(tbl_CELULAS);

// var parsetbl_CELULAS = JSON.parse(tbl_CELULAS);

// console.log(parsetbl_CELULAS);

     tbl_CELULAS.push(dados);

console.log(tbl_CELULAS);

//var JSON = JSON.stringify(tbl_CELULAS);

  console.log(JSON);
```

Esta uma confusão pois não estou sabendo montar a logica de forma a solucionar o problema. O que preciso é antes de inserir, buscar o que já tenho no localStorage, assim inserindo em ultima posição o que acabei de buscar, depois por ultimo salvar novamente no localStorage.

Comment: se precisa manter uma estrutura similar a uma tabela, não seja melhor utilizar o [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)?

Comment: @TobyMosque Eu utilizo, porém o indexedDB esta me dando problema com portabilidade em androids antigos, e a solução para nao ter mais dor de cabeça é esta

Comment: conhece o [`Storage.js`](https://github.com/lcavadas/Storage.js), ele promete uma interface unica para `DOM Storage`, `WebSQL` e `IndexedDB`. você pode informar qual tecnologia vai usar, se não o fizer ele vai tentar utilizar o `IndexedDB`, então o `WebSQL`, por fim o `localStorage`.

Comment: @TobyMosque Porém como faria para utilizar as tabelas ?

Comment: `storage(function (context) { context.set("nome entidade", { id: 2, desc: "desc" }, function () { context.get("nome entidade", 1, function(value) { console.log (value.desc) })})})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O localStorage guarda strings. Quando queres fazer reset deves passar strings ao setter, ou seja em vêz de `localStorage.setItem("tbl_TABELA01", []);`  deves ter `localStorage.setItem("tbl_TABELA01", '[]');`

Se queres ter certeza da ordem da gravação tens de usar arrays. Usando Objetos, e `Object.keys()`, não te retorna chaves por ordem de inserção.

Quando fazes `var tbl_CELULAS = localStorage.getItem("tbl_CELULAS");` isso retorna-te uma string e não um pointeiro que podes alterar por referência. No localStorage tens de ler tudo (em string) e escrever tudo de novo (em string) para gravar mudanças.

Esses aspetos que referi são importantes. Assim para o que queres fazer seria algo assim:

```
// fazer o reset
["tbl_TABELA01", "tbl_TABELA02", "tbl_TABELA03"].forEach(function(str) {
    localStorage.setItem(str, '[]');
});


var nome = $("#lblNome").val();
var telefone = $("#lblTelefone").val();

var tbl_CELULAS = localStorage.getItem("tbl_CELULAS"); // buscar a string que está gravada
var dados = JSON.parse(tbl_CELULAS); // para ler e mudar como uma array
var novosDados = { // criar um novo objeto
    lbNome: nome,
    lbTelefone: telefone
};
dados.push(novosDados); // inserir na variável/array
var json = JSON.stringify(dados); // para voltar a ter tudo em string com os novos dados
localStorage.setItem("tbl_CELULAS", json); // escrever a string no localStorage
```

---

## Nota:

não uses `var JSON = JSON.stringify(tbl_CELULAS);`! vais estar a apagar o método nativo. Quanto muito com letra pequena, para ser outra variável.

Comment: tinha um pequeno erro na inicialização dos objetos, no mais ficou à resposta ficou perfeita.

Comment: @TobyMosque obrigado!

Comment: Me tire então apenas mais uma duvida, tenho também um JSON vindo do AJAX, como faria para salva-lo ? De forma mais automatizada possível ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues se esse JSON está em string grava diretamente, senão tens de fazer `var string = JSON.stringify(dadosDoAjax);`. Podes verificar fazendo `alert(typeof dadosDoAjax);` para saber que _Tipo_ é retornado pelo ajax.